# ICommand and understanding the logic

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, icommand

I am currently trying to get my head around how Icommands work. I have a sample project. https://github.com/alicanerdogan/HamburgerMenu just to play around with and i am having trouble setting up a simple click event.

**MainWindow.cs**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, ICommand
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
            gridder.Children.Add(dash);
        }
  }
}
```

I understand that the execute runs the code I believe. as you can see i am just adding a user control to the grid. I am having trouble understanding how you add multiple click events or commands in this case. 
**MenuItem.cs**

```
 public ICommand SelectionCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SelectionCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectionCommandProperty, value); }
        }



        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SideMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

This is then bound to the button in the resource dictionary.
**MenuItem.xaml**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SideMenuItem">
                    <Button x:Name="ListBoxItemButton"  Command="{TemplateBinding SelectionCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

I understand this works as a template and then can be used within a window. in the `mainWindow.xaml` I have set up the menu and loads fine, when an item is pressed the execute method is performed.
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Local:SideMenu Background="#FFFF9203" MenuIconColor="White" SelectionIndicatorColor="White" MenuItemForeground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <Local:SideMenu.Content>
                <Local:SideMenuItem Icon="Images/home.png" Text="Home" SelectionCommand="{Binding ElementName=this_}" />
                <Local:SideMenuItem Icon="Images/settings.png" Text="Settings" />
            </Local:SideMenu.Content>
        </Local:SideMenu>
```

So to clarify what im after is how do i assign each MenuItem with a different command and this may be striaght forward but at the moment finding it confusing, why would you do it this way compared to what i think is a simple button with a click event?

Comment: You know MVVM and that WPF is designed for MVVM? There are lots of basic examples you will find when searching for WPF MVVM ICommand. First hit: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example

Comment: I'll try to keep the style of the previous comment)
Also if you don't quite understand the reasoning behind implementing commands then try to search for "Command Pattern" and "Composition Pattern".